# What must I do if the browser validator says that the "item is not focusable"?

Tags: html, css

I have this form:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="some" id="some-1" required>
        <label for="some-1"><span></span>Some 1</label>
    <br><br>
    <input type="radio" name="some" id="some-2" required>
        <label for="some-2"><span></span>Some 2</label>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And I have this CSS for radio inputs:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label span,input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin: -2px 8px 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"] + label span {
    background: url([long url]) no-repeat;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
    background: url([long url]) no-repeat;
}
```

I know that for the browser validator I must show all radio inputs, but how do I do it in my case?

[Example on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/dpdyqsfu/1/)

Comment: And yes, i know, that i can do it using another css for radio input, but how i can do it if radio input hidden?

Comment: What do you mean by “browser validator”?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela i talk about html5 - http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

Comment: that does not answer my question. What “browser validator” says something in what situation?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela browser shows erors, for exmaple, if i set on radio required and not select it, browser must say that i need to select one of radios.

Comment: That’s what you are asking the browser to do, by using the `required` attribute. And it’s different from anything you say in the question, and from what you say in the title, which are different things. So what is your question?